# Prevent Dbeaver from closing output tabs automatically after CSV export

Tags: csv, dbeaver

I have 3 queries I need to run.

I would like to run all of them and export all of them to their own CSV.

DBeaver populates the results of the 3 queries in each of their own tab (great), however, after I export 1 of them, a tab automatically closes. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a strange behaviour I can reproduce. Also, a little erratic. The only workaround I found was to pin the tabs (in right click menu of the tab).

Comment: OK glad it is not just me! You are exporting those as csv right?

Comment: Just tried it, it still disappears even after pinning all tabs.

Comment: Yesterday, I updated to 23.2.3, and now it does not happen at all. No tab closes, neither pinned nor unpinned. Please, give it a try.